# Usage of remote sensing to derive meteorological parameters be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am not sure if I can recall perfectly but somebody mentioned this in a meta posting once. Would the usage of remote sensing to calculate meteorological/oceanographical  parameters be on topic ? I meant the process of deriving the values or would that belong better in a GIS SE ?

Comment: that seems to be on topic

Comment: From the satellite instrumentation of TRMM the process to derive rainfall values would that be on topic ? I presume it can be split up into smaller questions and each question leading to the next. On topic ?

Comment: @gansub Yes, certainly on-topic.

Comment: I agree, on topic. Meteorology & oceanography are earth sciences & how data is collected for research in these fields is on topic. GIS is more about how data is used & presented.

Comment: @gerrit - I have asked the question that I mentioned I would.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remote sensing applications to earth or planetary sciences is on-topic.